# How to reuse the variables in capistrano unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, unicorn

I configured my deploy.rb with certain variables. For example

```
set :application, "rails3"
```

I am deploying my application using unicorn server which has the configuration under

> config/unicorn/development.rb

In this file I configured the variable pid_path = "/home/user/#{application}".

How to reuse the value from deploy.rb